# How to display data in expandable listview in android studio?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to get data from server and need to display it in Expandable list view.I am using AsyncTask to get data from server. But i am confuse how to set adapter for this situation and how to use it. I am new in android. please help me out to do this. First, in parent list i want to display category and in child list i want to display subcategories. Both parent and child data is on server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your list into ArrayList and then set to arrayAdapter like this.. arrayList.add(i)  ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hashMap for it. Like this

```
private void prepareListData() {
ArrayList<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

// Adding child data
listDataHeader.add("Top 50");
listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

// Adding child data
List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
top250.add("The Godfather");
top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
top250.add("The Dark Knight");
top250.add("12 Angry Men");

List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
nowShowing.add("Turbo");
nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
nowShowing.add("Red 2");
nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

this is how you usually add data to hashmap, so u can adjust according to the data coming from your server.